# Initial condition true everywhere but on a boundary, when NDSolving with a TensorProductGrid discretization

Tags: differential-equations

I am now focusing on using NDSolve with the method of lines and the TensorProductGrid spatial discretization to integrate PDEs. My problem is to integrate the wave equation from t=0 to t=2 with an initial flat shape and zero speed between x=0 and x=1, a harmonic drive on the left, and matched impedances on both sides. Here is my encoding:

```
eq = D[v[t, x], {t, 2}] - D[v[t, x], {x, 2}] == 0;
ics = {v[0, x] == 0, ((D[v[t, x], t]) /. t -> 0) == 0};
drive[t_] = Sin[2 Pi 2. t];
bcs = {(D[v[t, x], x] /. x -> 0) - (D[v[t, x], t] /. x -> 0) + 2 drive'[t] ==0,
       (D[v[t, x], x] /. x -> 1) + (D[v[t, x], t] /. x -> 1) == 0}
sol = NDSolveValue[{eq, ics, bcs} // Flatten, v, {t, 0, 2}, {x, 0, 1},
   Method -> {"MethodOfLines", "SpatialDiscretization" -> "TensorProductGrid"}, 
   MaxStepSize -> 0.01]
```

As expected, I obtain a warning *NDSolveValue::ibcinc: Warning: boundary and initial conditions are inconsistent.*. As well as a completely wrong result. This is because my zero initial speed is valid everywhere except at x=0, where the bcs gives an initial speed of 8Pi.

How to correct my code to indicate that the initial condition is not valid at x=0?

Thanks.

PS1: I know that the finite element method and Neumann values do the job automatically. I want to learn the finite difference method.

PS2: I don't want to use a cosine for the drive.

Comment: To be more specific, just add `Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
  "DifferentiateBoundaryConditions" -> {True, "ScaleFactor" -> 100}}` to `NDSolveValue`. Still the `eerr` warning comes up, but the estimated error is small and the solution is indeed accurate enough. You can compare the result to the one given by e.g. `Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
  "DifferentiateBoundaryConditions" -> {True, "ScaleFactor" -> 100}, 
  "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", "MaxPoints" -> 200, 
    "MinPoints" -> 200, "DifferenceOrder" -> 2}}`.

Comment: Thanks a lot xzczd ! If I understand well the answer 3 of the already answered question, it is not possible to tell NDSolve that an ic does not apply at a boundary with the method of lines and finite differences :-(.

Comment: I had already tried "DifferentiateBoundaryConditions" -> True but not with a scale factor of 100! The solution is however negatively biased (-1.2 to 0.8 instead of -1 to 1) and it improves very slowly with the scale factor. Now that I have understood that there is no way to really solve the problem, I prefer to multiply my drive by a fast branching function with zero initial derivative. Like this there is no inconsistency, no warning, and no bias on the solution. What should I do with my duplicate question ?

Comment: It's OK to keep the duplicate question as a guidepost, please don't take it as kind of punishment. :)